# How to change the "Start in" path in a shortcut for an application created by Electron Builder?

Tags: windows, electron, shortcut, electron-builder, shortcut-file

I build my application (nsis) in Windows with this instruction:

```
electron-builder --win --x64
```

For convenience I also use `asar: false`

The "Start in" folder by default is this one:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\app-name
```

But I need this other one:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Programs\app-name\resources\app
```

I only see [these options](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis) related to the shortcuts:

> - `createDesktopShortcut = true Boolean | “always”` - Whether to create desktop shortcut. Set to always if to recreate also on reinstall (even if removed by user).
> - `createStartMenuShortcut = true Boolean` - Whether to create start menu shortcut.
> - `menuCategory = false Boolean | String` - Whether to create submenu for start menu shortcut and program files directory. If true, company name will be used. Or string value.
> - `shortcutName String` - The name that will be used for all shortcuts. Defaults to the application name.

I can workaround this by using `process.chdir()`

```
const is_dev = require('electron-is-dev');
if (!is_dev) {
    process.chdir('path/to/resources/app');
}
```

But, is there a cleaner way to change the path "Start in" folder in `electron-builder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIS uses `$OutDir` (usually the same as `$InstDir`) as the start-in directory when it creates shortcuts. Not sure if you can change this variable before the shortcuts are created in electron-builder but it should not be your first priority to change it.

Applications should **not** depend on the working directory when they are started, required resources should be loaded relative to the .exe and/or relative to special folders (`%appdata%` and `%localappdata%` etc.). When users manually create shortcuts or starts your application from the command-line/open with/drag&drop/whatever the working directory can be any directory and you should accept this and fix the application instead of relying on a fragile shortcut property.

Comment: You are right. Then, my workaround is the correct way to proceed, just with `process.chdir(app.getAppPath())` would be enough